# How to create different user ID for every concurrent user for running Gatling test plan using Taurus Blazer

Tags: scala, gatling, taurus

In taurus config file, I am executing a Gatling script test plan through 50 concurrent users at a time. Every concurrent user must have different IDs when they each execute the test plan.  I searched online docs and stack overflow posts for solutions and came across feeders. Tried using feeders as suggested but I am not convinced that it works. I might be missing something.

What I tried:

Scala script:

```
.
.
val feeder = Iterator.continually(Map(("userId", {random.nextInt(150000)}.toString)))
.
.
.
val TestPlan: ChainBuilder = {
    feed(feeder)
      .exec(
          .put(baseURL)
          .header("UserId", "testuser_${userId}")
          .body("Hello World!")
          .check(status.is(200))
      )
}
```

Taurus Configuration:

```
execution:
  - executor: gatling
    concurrency: 50
    ramp-up: 1m
    hold-for: 9m
    threshold: 100
    # iterations: 5
    scenario: TestPlanSimulation
```

This configuration uses 50 concurrent users at a time each executing the test plan, totally runs for 10 mins.

FYI, I am new to scala and load testing using Gatling and Taurus.

So my question is how to generate separate userIDs for every concurrent user executing the test plan in this context.

Please comment if you have any questions.

Comment: Your code will generate a random user id for each user. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Instead of using random Ids for each user, Is there a way to assign different user ID to each concurrent user systematically?